# How to check the title bar height of Xamarin Android activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Can this be done programmatically?

Or alternatively, can the height be set declaratively, so that I at least know what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Android.App.ActionBar` is what you're looking for, but the Height property is Read Only. unfortunately.